# Plot RidgeCV coefficients as a function of the regularization

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, regression

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.linear_model import RidgeCV
tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
X = tips.drop(columns=['tip','sex', 'smoker', 'day', 'time'])
y = tips['tip']
alphas = 10**np.linspace(10,-2,100)*0.5
ridge_clf = RidgeCV(alphas=alphas,scoring='r2').fit(X, y)
ridge_clf.score(X, y)
```

I wanted to plot the following graph for RidgeCV. I don't see any option to do that like GridSearhCV. I appreciate your suggestions!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no indication what the colors stand for. I assume they stand for features and we investigate the size of each feature weight as function of alpha. Here is my solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import RidgeCV
tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
X = tips.drop(columns=['tip','sex', 'smoker', 'day', 'time'])
y = tips['tip']
alphas = 10**np.linspace(10,-2,100)*0.5
w = list()
for a in alphas:
    ridge_clf = RidgeCV(alphas=[a],cv=10).fit(X, y)
    w.append(ridge_clf.coef_)
w = np.array(w)
plt.semilogx(alphas,w)
plt.title('Ridge coefficients as function of the regularization')
plt.xlabel('alpha')
plt.ylabel('weights')
plt.legend(X.keys())
```

Output:
[image: Plot]
Since you only have two features in X there are only two lines.

Comment: I wanted to use  `RidgeCV` to perfrom corss-validation. Sklearn has also documented the solution that you provided. It is a general practice to perform cross-validation.

Comment: Updated my answer and added `RidgeCV`.

Comment: Why would you perform cross validation with a single alpha?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_ridge_path.html) is the code for generating the plot that you had posted.

Firstly, we need to understand that `RidgeCV` would not return the `coef` for each alpha value that we had fed in the `alphas` param.

The motivation behind having the `RidgeCV` is that it will try for different alpha values mentioned in `alphas` param, then based on cross validation scoring, it will return the best alpha along with the fitted model.

Hence, the only way to get the `coef` for each alpha value using cv is iterate through RidgeCV using each alpha value.

Example:

```
# Author: Fabian Pedregosa -- <fabian.pedregosa@inria.fr>
# License: BSD 3 clause

print(__doc__)

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import linear_model

# X is the 10x10 Hilbert matrix
X = 1. / (np.arange(1, 11) + np.arange(0, 10)[:, np.newaxis])
y = np.ones(10)

# #############################################################################
# Compute paths

n_alphas = 200
alphas = np.logspace(-10, -2, n_alphas)

coefs = []
for a in alphas:
    ridge = linear_model.RidgeCV(alphas=[a], fit_intercept=False, cv=3)
    ridge.fit(X, y)
    coefs.append(ridge.coef_)

# #############################################################################
# Display results

ax = plt.gca()

ax.plot(alphas, coefs)
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_xlim(ax.get_xlim()[::-1])  # reverse axis
plt.xlabel('alpha')
plt.ylabel('weights')
plt.title('RidgeCV coefficients as a function of the regularization')
plt.axis('tight')
plt.show()
```

[image]